# Unexpected behavior of sstableLoader

Tags: database, cassandra, disk, disk-io

I'm working on two different machines and both have different hard disk storage and different cassandra version.

**machine 1**
SSD hard disk, Cassandra 2.1.13

**machine 2**
HDD hard disk, Cassandra 2.1.3

Now I transferred data of one CF from **machine 2** to **machine 1** using **SSTableLoader** utility. Till this step it was working fine and data were also transferred successfully.

But By mistake I truncated the data on **machine 2** for the same CF. In order to recover back the data I used the same concept. I tried to transfer the data from **machine 1** to **machine 2**.

And meanwhile I found some strange logs

1. 16:22:53.956 [main] DEBUG o.a.c.io.sstable.SSTableReader - Cannot
   deserialize SSTable Summary File
   ./data/data/sstableloadertest/typestest-8e68e811f56511e59d60297061e28552/sstableloadertest-typestest-ka-57-Summary.db:
   Cannot deserialize SSTable Summary component because the
   DiskAccessMode was changed!

And it also deleted the *summary.db component of sstable.

First I thought It happened due to different cassandra version But I was wrong.

Anyone can tell me why is this happening ?

Comment: Whats the disk_access_mode in cassandra.yaml set to in both machine1 and machine2?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Both machines are using almost default cassandra.yaml so there is no such property.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink and both machine are `x86_64`

Answer (score 1):

The deleted summary file should be fine. Might be worth just deleting it yourself and restarting server. The [summary file](http://distributeddatastore.blogspot.com/2013/08/cassandra-sstable-storage-format.html) just stores indexes to the partitions and can be rebuilt on startup.

The default disk access mode is auto which is set based on if its a 32bit or 64bit architecture [1](http://distributeddatastore.blogspot.com/2013/08/cassandra-sstable-storage-format.html)[2]. So likely your first or second system is using a 32bit version of jdk and other is not. Check in logs, there should be a line like

```
INFO  [main] 2016-03-16 16:45:11,464 CassandraDaemon.java:424 - JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_45
```

If machine2 is running 64bit and machine1 was 32bit jvm then just set the `disk_access_mode` property in cassandra.yaml to `standard`. If machine2 is running 32bit jvm and machine1 was 64bit, upgrade jvm on machine2.

This will likely cause issues with all your other summary files set for other mode though. So ultimately it should work just letting it get rebuilt.

[1](http://distributeddatastore.blogspot.com/2013/08/cassandra-sstable-storage-format.html) https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/8097d390a285c20aa47954750a80d176a826e47b/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/config/DatabaseDescriptor.java#L313

[2] https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/8097d390a285c20aa47954750a80d176a826e47b/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/config/DatabaseDescriptor.java#L1931

Comment: I think you are right I'll check it tomorrow and will update you. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: But my both machines are 64 architecture not sure about version of JDK

Comment: edited with workaround, can set disk_access_mode in machine2 to match machine1 or upgrade jvm.

Comment: I'll accept your answer after checking it. Thank you very much.

Comment: I checked the system.log for both machine and I found they are using same architecture.
<br/>
**machine 1 system.log**  `INFO  [main] 2016-03-29 15:56:08,235 CassandraDaemon.java:172 - JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_20`<br/>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>
**machine 2 system.log**  `INFO  [main] 2016-01-12 11:40:23,159 CassandraDaemon.java:114 - JVM vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_66`

Can you please explain the situation ?

Comment: Just to reiterate above - can ignore all this since the summary is rebuilt on startup, but im curious as well. Can you open any Summary.db from each machine1 and machine2: `strings blarg-Summary.db` and see if its which is listed as "mmap" or "standard"? Maybe theres a jvm bug between update 20 or 66 that broke the arch detection. Using jconsole or https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools and get values of the System properties? `java.lang:type=Runtime` `SystemProperties`. ie `java -jar sjk.jar mx -mg -s 127.0.0.1:7199 -b java.lang:type=Runtime -f SystemProperties`

Comment: Both machines Summary file has 
`mmap` 
`mmap` .

Comment: Can you tell me one thing 

Why SSTableLoader does remove `summary.db` file always ?

Comment: if the summary file doesnt match the indexing used by the reader it deletes it because it wont use it. The summary file isnt really needed, it just speeds up start time since it so it doesnt have to rebuild it. can you `java -version` on whatever system or wherever your running sstable loader from? Do you have multiple jdks installed on it?

Comment: without summary file you can't truncate the table

Comment: I created two instance of cassandra on machine 2 itself. and tried to load data of one cassandra instance to another instance and it still says 

`Cannot deserialize SSTable Summary File /home/barala/Downloads/Cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.1.3.2/data/data/sstableloadertest/typestest-f36ad9d0f4a711e5807e55bc51b0510e/sstableloadertest-typestest-ka-2287-Summary.db: Cannot deserialize SSTable Summary component because the DiskAccessMode was changed!
11:52:10.041 [main] DEBUG o.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils - Deleting sstableloadertest-typestest-ka-2287-Summary.db`

Comment: Can open a https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA to get it looked at more, but its something you can ignore